# Problem in typing a symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to type this character as a symbol for energy:

[image]

But when I type capital u, it is shown as:

[image]

Please help me find the solution. Thanks

Comment: Can you please add an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/152550)? Perhaps you have loaded a font package that changes the normal font of the document. Try with: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}$U$\end{document}` and see if that works.

Comment: You have selected a different font than the default, hence you get a different capital U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `U` from the default Computer Modern font you can just define it using another name.  I used `\energy` because that is what you want to use it for.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Change the main math font
\usepackage{mathpazo}

% Get Computer Modern ``U'' back under different name
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\energy}{\mathalpha}{cmletters}{`U}

\begin{document}

$U \energy$

\end{document}
```

[image]